# Is it possible to get wireless name with Flash

Tags: java, html, flash, browser

Is it possible to get wireless name and wirelss MAC address using Flash? Or I should use Java?

Comment: Related: [Is JavaScript or Flash able to extract the MAC address from a browser?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/is-javascript-or-flash-able-to-extract-the-mac-address-from-a-browser). It looks like you're gonna need server side technology to handle this like Java.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277440/getting-the-mac-address-of-a-client-with-a-browser